# How to decrypt information encrypted by Java Cipher using Mysql 8?

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes, mysql-8.0

**Context**

I am encrypting information from my application then I save the encrypted information in my MySql 8.0 database, this is the way to encrypt and decrypt the information in my application:

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY_ENCRYPT_BD.getBytes(), "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(c.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    if (dbData != null) {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY_ENCRYPT_BD.getBytes(), "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(c.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData.getBytes("UTF-8"))), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return dbData;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The encrypted information is saved in varchar(65) column with utf8mb4 charset.

**What I am looking for**

I am looking to decrypt the encrypted information but through MySql 8.0, I have tried several ways trying to do the same process in Java code but all I get is a Null result.

This is the query

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(primer_nombre),'passwordKey')   FROM info_personal_usuario;
```

**Hint**

I have managed to decrypt the data but using Mysql 5.7 with the following query.

```
SELECT Cast(Aes_decrypt(From_base64(primer_nombre),"passwordkey")
AS CHAR(50)) primer_nombre FROM info_personal_usuario
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried to change the cipher mode

```
SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
SET @init_vector = RANDOM_BYTES(16);
SET @key_str = SHA2('pwdKey',512);
SELECT Cast(Aes_decrypt(From_base64(primer_nombre),@key_str,@init_vector) AS CHAR(50)) primer_nombre FROM info_personal_usuario;
```

Comment: the encryption differ independent that they use the same name

Comment: @nbk what do you mean? Is java's encryption method different from MySQL?

Comment: i mean that the algorithm and implementation in java differs from that in mysql, so they both can't decrypt the text from each other, that is a basic fact that even can occur in different version of a programming language

Comment: @nbk so there is not way to get the decrypted information?

Comment: Is it encrypted AND encoded BASE64 or just encoded?

Comment: @LMC as you can see in the code, it is encrypted and encoded Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(c.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));

Comment: May be you are trying to decrypt with MySql something encrypted with Java.

Comment: @LMC yes it is what im trying to do...is there any way to do that?

Comment: Tip: always provide a charset: `KEY_ENCRYPT_BD.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO:_8859_1)` for instance.

Comment: It should be possible I guess. Look at [block_encryption_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt), both sides should agree on configuration

Comment: You should the MSQL docs what algorithm, mode and padding is in use for AES-ENCRYPT. Your Java algo seems to be AES ECB-mode and PKCS5 padding, but that's guessed as you left out this information.

Comment: MySQL will use `aes-128-ecb` by default. Unless your cipher is configured the same, MySQL can't properly decrypt the value (and return null). What is the value of `ALGORITHM` in `Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);`? We need to know if the default (`AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`) or some other value is used.

Comment: @TasosP.  Question Edited. Yes the mode used for Java is "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", so MySql uses 128 key and Java is 256 so I have to change MySql from 128 to 256 but I dont know how...

Comment: @MichaelFehr Question Edited. Yes the mode used for Java is "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", so MySql uses 128 key and Java is 256 so I have to change MySql from 128 to 256 but I dont know how...

Comment: You can try `SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';` as  described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_block_encryption_mode)

Comment: @TasosP. I have tried to change the encryption mode but it continues returning null. Check my edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [AttributeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) responsible for data encryption uses `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` cipher, which translates to:

- AES encryption with the default 128bit key length
- ECB mode
- PKCS5 padding

In order to decrypt data encrypted with the above method with MySQL's [AES_DECRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt) you need to configure it with the same settings (also knowing the encryption key will help ;-) ). In this case, you should use:

```sql
SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-ecb';
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(column_name),'encryption_key') as  char(64));
```

Sample encryption code:

```java
        final String KEY_ENCRYPT_BD = "TEST#EST@#ST!@#T";
        final String ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
        final String data = "Secret";

        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY_ENCRYPT_BD.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(c.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

// Output is: pkIRP/y09TKfv5Y8nPrFRw==
```

Sample decryption code:

```sql
SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-ecb';
SELECT cast(Aes_decrypt(From_base64('pkIRP/y09TKfv5Y8nPrFRw=='),'TEST#EST@#ST!@#T') as  char(50));
```

[Output](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/RD9KDE9RoRi9sDUfy75Kv/0) is `Secret`

Notes:

- Your `utf8mb4` character set is irrelevant since you only store base64 strings. Perhaps a [binary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) datatype might save you a few bytes per record (and avoid `base64` altogether).
- Your MySQL 5.7 server might already have `block_encryption_mode` set to `aes-128-ecb` which explains why decryption works

Answer (score 0):

The Below MySQL Query decrypts the string

SELECT description, AES_DECRYPT(description,'key') FROM test_table;

Comment: Please consider to edit or remove your answer due the title question was changed and your answer does not solve the problem